# NetworkStream.read() reads all bytes but won't convert to string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, networkstream

I am trying to read the response of the server when attempting to log on using `networkStream.read()` using the following code:

```
if (connectionStream.DataAvailable && connectionStream.CanRead)
{
    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[64];
    string responseMessage = string.Empty;
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        numberOfBytesRead = connectionStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        responseMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);

    } while (connectionStream.DataAvailable);

    Debug.Log("Message:" + responseMessage);

    #breakpoint 
    if (responseMessage.Contains("OK"))
    {
        Debug.Log("logon sucessful");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Logon denied!");
    }
}
```

By inspecting my local variables at `breakpoint` i know the `Read()` is excecuted without problem as `numberOfBytesRead` is set to 32, and `myReadBuffer` is filled with 32 bytes (all bytes in `myReadBuffer` match the bytes sent by the server). However after trying to extract the string from `myReadbuffer` using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` the string is still empty (Visual studio also says it is empty at the breakpoint), even though `myReadBuffer` isn't.

The bytes in `myReadBuffer` read:

```
32 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
76 79 71 79
78 58 32 48
59 79 75 59
32 83 83 61
54 66 67 0
```

which translates to: `_  _  _    _  _  _  _  _  _  _  L  O  G  O  N  :     0  ;  O  K  ;     S  S  =  5  A  8  _`

Any suggestions as to what can cause this?

Comment: ASCII, thankfully, can be decoded byte by byte (Most other encodings, such as UTF8, you couldn't do this for). You should still, though, supply `numberOfBytesRead` to `GetString` so that you're not converting bytes in the buffer that didn't come from the network.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I am actually supplying `numberOfBytesRead` in the actual code, just forgot to add it here, edited now.

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server contains some `null ('\0')` characters. Despite what the docs on [Strings (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/) say about null termination in C#:

> There is no null-terminating character at the end of a C# string; therefore a C# string can contain any number of embedded null characters ('\0').

Unity does not seem to comply to this, and actually *does* terminate a string after a `null` character has been encountered. Though I couldn't find any references to this in the unity docs.

The fix i ended up going with was replacing the null characters by spaces (Could also remove the null characters completely, but i want to know the characters were there at some point) like so: `responseMessage = responseMessage.Replace('\x0', '\x0020');`

While creating this post i figured it out, but coulnd't find any other posts on SO describing my problem. So answering it myself for future references. If anyone has any other/better solutions or additional information i'd still be glad to hear/accept that.